# codeigniter how to submit multiple rows with the same name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried the following model view controller but i need to submit multiple rows at a time: please can any one help me how to achieve this?

**this is my controller:**

```
function add_item(){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name', 'Item Name', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->model('mdl_item');
            $data['main_content'] = 'backend/items/add_item';
            $data['title'] = 'Create item';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('mdl_item');
            $data = $this->input->post();
            $this->mdl_item->create_item($data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Items successfully created');
            redirect('admin/items', 'refresh');
        }


    }
```

**this is my model:**

```
function create_item($data)
    {

            $data['expiry_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(element('expiry_date', $data)));
            $crop_data = elements(array(
            'item_name',

            ), $data);
            $add_item = $this->db->insert_string('items', $crop_data);
            $this->db->query($add_item);


    }
```

**this is my View:**

```
 <?php echo form_open('admin/items/add_item', 'id="item_form_validate"'); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 jumbotron">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name[]" value="<?php echo set_value('item_name'); ?>">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name[]" value="<?php echo set_value('item_name'); ?>">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name[]" value="<?php echo set_value('item_name'); ?>">


 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="submit"><span class="icon-checkmark"></span> <?php echo lang('Submit'); ?></button>
 </form>
```

Comment: what is the current output of this?

Answer (score 1):

change the code `set_rules('item_name',` in Controllers

```
...
        function add_item(){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name', 'Item Name', 'trim|required');
```

to this `set_rules('item_name[]'`

```
...
        function add_item(){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name[]', 'Item Name', 'required');
```

and trim the value after you pass it